# Can I pull my local Redis data from a url?

Tags: api, url, redis

For example, is it possible to do something like:

`localhost:6379/?command=keys&a1=*`

and be returned the data. Similar to an API.

Comment: Neat idea. Nice and terse. I think you would need a redis proxy to encode the request and decode the responses. What language ?

Comment: Python. I've setup redis-py, the defacto Python wrapper for Redis, but how do I do the next step, i.e. allowing url fetches and such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**webd.is**](http://webd.is/) does that, its an HTTP webserver written in C.

#### Main features:

> - GET and POST are supported, as well as PUT for file uploads.
> - JSON output by default, optional JSONP parameter (?jsonp=myFunction or ?callback=myFunction).
> - Raw Redis 2.0 protocol output with .raw suffix
> - HTTP 1.1 pipelining (70,000 http requests per second on a desktop Linux machine.)
> - Multi-threaded server, configurable number of worker threads.
> - Connects to Redis using a TCP or UNIX socket.
> - Restricted commands by IP range (CIDR subnet + mask) or HTTP Basic Auth, returning 403 errors.
> - Possible Redis authentication in the config file.
> - URL-encoded parameters for binary data or slashes and question marks. For instance, %2f is decoded as / but not used as a command
>     separator.
> - Logs, with a configurable verbosity.
> - Cross-origin requests, usable with XMLHttpRequest2 (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - CORS).
> - Optional daemonize.
> - Default root object: Add "default_root": "/GET/index.html" in webdis.json to substitute the request to / with a Redis request.
> - HTTP request limit with http_max_request_size (in bytes, set to 128MB by default).
> - Database selection in the URL, using e.g. /7/GET/key to run the command on DB 7.

Otherwise that is a very basic project [**redis-rest**](https://github.com/antoniojrossi/redis-rest/blob/master/redis-rest.rb) in ruby you may want to take a look at.

Comment: +1 didn't know this existed and was looking for something similar.

Comment: If you are using Redis you may want to take a look at Redsmin Redis GUI too http://redsmin.com :)